# VSTO not working for Outlook 2013

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, vsto, ms-office

I have a VSTO for Outlook 2007. That works on Outlook 2010 as well. Now I have upgrade my office 2010 to 2013. My VSTO works here as well. But the issue is I have written code to add a **ContextMenuItem** in Right Click menu. To implement this I have implemented **Application.AttachmentContextMenuDisplay** Method. Here is my code snippet:

```
 Private Sub Application_AttachmentContextMenuDisplay(ByVal CommandBar As    Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBar, ByVal Attachments As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AttachmentSelection) Handles Application.AttachmentContextMenuDisplay

     Dim DVCmdBarPopup As Office.CommandBarPopup
        DVCmdBarPopup = CommandBar.Controls.Add _
            (Office.MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, , , 3, True)

        With DVCmdBarPopup
            .Caption ="Menu"   
            .BeginGroup = True
            .Visible = True
            .Tag = "Hello World."
            .TooltipText = "Hello World."   
        End With

 End Sub
```

this code works fine for Outlook 2007 as 2010. But when I install Office 2013 and I tried to  build My vsto then it shows me error like this.

"**the project currently contains references to more than one version of office, a direct reference to version 14.0.0.0 and an indirect reference (through 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Explorer.CommandBars') to version 15.0.0.0.**"
I have no idea what happens. Kindly reply if u have any ideas or faced this problem earlier.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

CommandBar.Controls.Add(Office.MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, , , 3, True)
is not supported for Outlook 2013.

I am also trying to port to Outlook 2013 but it fails.
"http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj229903.aspx".

If you are able to figure out anything from your end, please let me know.